# Append an XML file to another using LINQ TO XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have two XML files I want to append `Orderlist2.xml` to `Orderlist.xml`

Here is my code to achieve to this, but every time I run it I get an error: 
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Concat.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Concat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var xml1 = XDocument.Load("Orderlist.xml");
            var xml2 = XDocument.Load("Orderlist2.xml");


            xml1.Descendants("ListOrderItemsResult").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(xml2.Descendants("ListOrderItemsResult"));
            xml1.Save("Orderlist.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Orderlist.xml

```
<ListOrderItemsResponse
    xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>115-8324109-2580214</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00CXWANX2</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>UJ-D11Y-CDD4</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>36597396932386</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Isopropyl Alcohol 99% Technical Grade in one Gallon Poly Bottle.</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>2</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.60</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>54.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>92b66d69-c0e1-4549-9122-7846faf06644</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrderItemsResponse>
```

Orderlist2.xml

```
<ListOrderItemsResponse
    xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>104-0314222-2069825</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00D6NJRCU</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>CF-IVS1-49JR</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>36825199299522</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Titanium Dioxide, Five Lb Bag</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>12.49</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>0d81935c-2bde-4e46-8f4f-7d25cc13d322</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrderItemsResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the namespace in the XMLs, This should do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XNamespace ns = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";

        var xml1 = XDocument.Load("Orderlist.xml");
        var xml2 = XDocument.Load("Orderlist2.xml");

        xml1.Descendants(ns + "ListOrderItemsResult").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(xml2.Descendants(ns + "ListOrderItemsResult"));
        xml1.Save("Orderlist.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! why does the namespace have to be included?  If the XML code didn't include this line `xmlns=""https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01` could I run the code without having to declare the namespace?  What's its purpose?

Comment: @DanielTaki Yes, your code works fine when the XML doesn't have a namespace. The main goal of namespaces is to avoid name conflicts so that tags with the same name can be defined under different namespaces. In practice I haven't seen much use of them so far but it's generally advised to use them AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Because the xml has namespace,there is my code works fine,and sorry,I changed the `XDocument` to `XElement`

```
string xml1 = @"<ListOrderItemsResponse
    xmlns=""https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01"">
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>115-8324109-2580214</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00CXWANX2</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>UJ-D11Y-CDD4</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>36597396932386</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Isopropyl Alcohol 99% Technical Grade in one Gallon Poly Bottle.</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>2</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.60</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>54.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>92b66d69-c0e1-4549-9122-7846faf06644</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrderItemsResponse>";
    string xml2 = @"<ListOrderItemsResponse
    xmlns=""https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01"">
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>104-0314222-2069825</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>B00D6NJRCU</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>CF-IVS1-49JR</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>36825199299522</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Titanium Dioxide, Five Lb Bag</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>12.49</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>27.00</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds />
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>0d81935c-2bde-4e46-8f4f-7d25cc13d322</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrderItemsResponse>";
    var root1 = XElement.Parse(xml1);
    var root2 = XElement.Parse(xml2);
    root1.Elements(root1.GetDefaultNamespace() + "ListOrderItemsResult").Last().AddAfterSelf(root2.Elements(root2.GetDefaultNamespace() + "ListOrderItemsResult"));
```